# Django model relations [nesting and hierarchy]

Tags: django, database, model, relationship

I apologize in advance for the novice question and if it is already answered. I have searched multiple terms without getting a clear answer.

I'm trying to figure out a model schema and it's relationships in a Django project.

The questions that arise while doing this are as follows:

Regarding the first part of the code: (Country > State > City > University > Department > Subject):

- Are there too many levels of hierarchy? Any way to model it better or more efficiently?

  - I have been looking at nested relationships as well (serializers), but no clue if there's a better way to organize it.
- Is it a good practice to have models such as State or City with only one field in the hierarchy?

  - I mean, I need them, but not sure if they are avoidable due to their simplicity with another models relationship solution.

> - Can a "model" access its second/third/nth parent?  Eg: A subject can access easily its department via:
>
>   *Subject.objects.filter(department__name='Maths')*
>
>   But is it possible to access the University or State from the subject object? How?
>   ** Already answered by [daneil James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14689289/daneil-james)

Regarding the second part of the code (Person and laptop):

- I have a few roles in the models (president, dean, director, teacher). Some of those fields have a ManyToMany relation:

  - Eg: A teacher can be in more than one subject and a subject can have more than a teacher.

I was assuming that I could use the built-in users API and roles/groups for this matter. So at the end, president or teacher, are roles, but no idea how to implement it in that way or if it's a good idea.

- Regarding the laptops, let's say that the university has some laptops (ManyToOne relation), that's straightforward.

  - But those laptops are assigned to a department and a subject. Do I need a ForeignKey for University, Department and Subject in the laptop model?

How would it be possible to count them properly or have a registry?
University has 10 laptops, assigned to 2 departments and 5 subjects.

Again, I apologize if the questions are too basic.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Model Schema:** (pseudo-code)

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name: 
    extension:
    currency:
    <<president>>:

class State (models.Model)
    name:
    **country: models.ForeignKey(Country)**

class City (models.Model)
   name:
   **state: models.ForeignKey(State)**

class University(models.Model)
    name:
    address:
    <<dean>>:
    **city: models.ForeignKey(City)**
    laptop:

class Department(models.Model)
    name:
    <<director>>:
    **university: models.ForeignKey(University)**
    laptop:

class Subject(models.Model)
    name:
    description:
    <<teacher>>:
    **department: models.ForeignKey(Department)**
    laptop:
```

---

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name: 
    address:
    age:

class Laptop(models.Model):
    brand:
    model:
    serial:
    date:
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding
Can a "model" access its second/third/nth parent? Eg: A subject can access easily its department via:
Yes you can follow backward and forward relationship in django

```
`Subject.objects.filter(department__university__city__country = 'Your query')`
```

If relation is one to many at end of parent you could use `_set`

```
`Subject.objects.filter(department__university__city__country_set = 'Your query')`
```

Comment: Cool, thank you so much! 

I upvoted the answer, but my reputation doesn't allow to show the vote in the public post (or something like that)

Comment: Still understanding how it works, but I think that means that the post is solved? 
I mean, I would like to get some answers from other users to my other questions as well

PS: As said, just assuming and still novice, correct me if I'm worng :)

Comment: yes you can still wait for full detail answer but you can go anywhere forward or backward on chained relations